# Why using namespace & using namespace::var declarations doesn't result in ambiguity

Tags: c++

I recently saw in a c++ test the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace nmp1
{
  float foo = 100;
}

namespace nmp2
{
  float foo = -22;    
}

int main(int, char**) {
  using namespace nmp1;
  using nmp2::foo;

  cout << foo << endl;
}
```

My first thought was that this would result in ambiguity and an error while compiling, but after finishing the test I found out that this compiled without problems and printed -22.

What is the reason for this? As far as I know both **using** statements will make visible the namespaces contents to the main function scope which means having 2 variables with the same name.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives Looks like this is the right quote: "Using-directives are allowed only in namespace scope and in block scope. **From the point of view of unqualified name lookup** of any name after a using-directive and until the end of the scope in which it appears, every name from namespace-name is **visible as if it were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace** which contains both the using-directive and namespace-name". I'm not totally sure that I understand it completely right, so I leave the explanation to others:)

Comment: So, my understanding is that `using nmp2::foo` is the same as declaring `float foo` right here (you can check that it would conflict with `float foo;` declaration), while `using namespace nmp1` is essentially declaring `foo` in some outer scope (I'm not sure exactly which one), and therefore is overridden.